# Win32: How to access Windows Listview Header Control Filters

Tags: c++, winapi, c++builder

According to [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/header-controls#header-control-filters) you can add Filter bar to ListView :

> By specifying the HDS_FILTERBAR window style for a header control, you can enable the placement of filter edit boxes underneath the column headings. A filter button appears beside the edit box.

I can access filter strings via `HDITEM` and `HDTEXTFILTER` but how to change underlying Edits and Buttons ?

Let's assume i would like to change default filter text placeholder from "Enter text here" to "Type here" like it's possible with [Edit_SetCueBannerText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-edit_setcuebannertext#remarks) or change filter button look ?

Assumption : Windows Vista + , Common Control 6.0 +

Comment: I don't think it's safe to assume filter box or buttons are actually Edit and Button controls, and not just drawn elements. You can easily verify that checking header children list on HDN_BEGINFILTEREDIT for example.

Answer (score -2):

If you don't mind some hacks - you can get to child windows using for example `EnumChildWindows()` - then you may be able to send commands, etc. using the hwnd. Use "spy++" on your running program first to investigate the structure of parent/child window relations.